# OpenGL 3.0 Window Collision Detection

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, glsl

Can someone tell me how to make triangle vertices collide with edges of the screen?
For math library I am using GLM and for window creation and keyboard/mouse input I am using GLFW.
I created perspective matrix and simple array of triangle vertices.

Then I multiplied all this in vertex shader like:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0);
```

Projection matrix is defined as:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(
    45.0f, (GLfloat)screenWidth / (GLfloat)screenHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

I have fully working camera and projection. I can move around my "world" and see triangle standing there. The problem I have is I want to make sure that triangle collide with edges of the screen.

What I did was disable camera and only enable keyboard movement. Then I initialized translation matrix as `glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(xMove, yMove, -2.5f));` and scale matrix to scale by 0.4.

Now all of that is working fine. When I press RIGHT triangle moves to the right when I press UP triangle moves up etc... The problem is I have no idea how to make it stop moving then it hits edges.

This is what I have tried:

`triangleRightVertex.x` is `glm::vec3` object.

**0.4** is scaling value that I used in **scaling matrix**.

```
if(((xMove + triangleRightVertex.x) * 0.4f) >= 1.0f)
{
 cout << "Right side collision detected!" << endl; 
}
```

When I move triangle to the right it does detect collision when x of the third vertex(bottom right corner of triangle) collides with right side but it goes little bit beyond before it detects. But when I tried moving up it detected collision when half of the triangle was up.

I have no idea what to do here can someone explain me this please?

Comment: My solution is to create lines as window frame and check if point is in the line using line equation. I don't know if that is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the vertex coordinates of the triangle is transformed by the `model` matrix form model space to world space, by the `view` matrix from world space to view space and by the `projection` matrix from view space to clip space. `gl_Position` is the [Homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) in clip space and further transformed by a [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) from clip space to normalized device space. The normalized device space is a cube, with right, bottom, front of (-1, -1, -1) and a left, top, back of (1, 1, 1).
All the geometry which is in this (volume) cube is "visible" on the viewport.

In clip space the clipping of the scene is performed.
A point is in clip space if the `x`, `y` and `z` components are in the range defined by the inverted `w` component and the `w` component of the homogeneous coordinates of the point:

```
-w <=  x, y, z  <= w
```

What you want to do is to check if a vertex `x` coordinate of the triangle is clipped. SO you have to check if the `x` component of the clip space coordinate is in the view volume.

Calculate the clip space position of the vertices on the CPU, as it does the vertex shader.
The [glm library](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) is very suitable for things like that:

```
glm::vec3 triangleVertex = ... ; // new model coordinate of the triangle
glm::vec4 h_pos = projection * view * model * vec4(triangleVertex, 1.0);

bool x_is_clipped = h_pos.x < -h_pos.w || h_pos.x > h_pos.w;
```

If you don't know how the orientation of the triangle is transformed by the `model` matrix and `view` matrix, then you have to do this for all the 3 vertex coordinates of the triangle-

Comment: Hey man thank you very much! I totally forgot about the w component of the matrix -.- .. I even compared to the aspect ratio because I didnt know what is going on haha.I was about to do line equations /////